# Can I use present perfect to replace past perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

> A: When you went to the US last year, was it your first visit?
>
> B: No, **I'd been** there twice before.

Does it still make sense if I replace *I'd been* with *I've been*? If no, why not?

Comment: If you _had been_ there twice before and you went again, you now _have been_ there three times.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether B uses (1) Present Perfect or (2) Past Perfect in his reply. That choice simply depends on whether B wants to focus on the time when he last went to the US (in which case #2 is used to refer to things that happened *prior to* that point in past time) OR he wants to focus on his *current* state (that of having been to the US a total of *three* times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get rid of the abbreviations;

> A: When you went to the US last year, was it your first visit?

using the substitution

> No, I have been there twice before

“I have been to the US” implies that sometime in the past I went to the US and this fact is still true today. Here “have been” is ***used in the present perfect tense.***

Note Conjugation of the verb “to have” is as below.

> I have been; You have been; We have been; they have been; people have been

> He has been; She has been; It has been, Kate has been; One has been

And for the original

> B: No, I had been there twice before.

“Had been” basically follows similar parameters, but for **the past perfect tense** instead of present perfect. In this case, “had” doesn’t change depending on the subject (whether it is singular or plural)

> "Had been" is the past perfect tense and is used in all cases, singular and plural. The past perfect tense refers to something that began in the past and was still true at another time that also was in the past

---

*Yes it does make sense if you use the alternative phrase*.

Both sentences mean that he had visited the US twice, previous to his last visit.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of (mostly true) facts about the perfect tenses, but it doesn't actually answer the question. There is one incorrect statement: *have been* is the *present perfect tense*, not the *present perfect continuous tense.* The present perfect continuous tense is *I have been trying* or *I have been being* (although we don't often use *I have been being* because of the awkward repetition of the verb *be*).

Comment: [At the time of my visit last year (that is, in the past)] I _had_ been twice before (past perfect tense). [Now] I _have_ been three times.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes I stand corrected I had written *for the  present perfect tense ** in one section but for some strange reason had written *continuous in another sentence. Maybe a cut and paste or maybe I just lost it for a moment. Anyway thank you for your comment.